# Java - Two classes, same name, same package but in different folders

Tags: java

I have two classes that have the same class name and use the same package name. However, the two class files are located in different directories. One other thing that is different between the two is that each class has methods in it that do not appear in the other. In essence, I want to split the methods into two separate files using the same name but different folders.

Theoretically I would think that this is possible because the Java compiler does maintain the directory structure when it builds the output. So during runtime, if a method is called in the class, perhaps Java would look to find the method in whichever file had the method.

Is this even possible? I'm using IntelliJ and it seems to only let me pick one of the class files but not both when it needs to resolve a method.

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? When you say that they have the same package name, is it *entirely* the same? As in, all the directories are identical?

Comment: Directories are different but the package name in the class file is the same. And the filename for the class is the same.

Comment: You cannot have multiple classes with the same name and package in one classpath without asking for problems.

Comment: Directories are packages...

Comment: @MCMastery You're right. I forgot to mention that the directories are the same but located in different modules, meaning that the root directory is different but the source code path that gets compiled is the same in both classes. In any case, it does not appear that this is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Java will not "look to find the method", it will resolve a single .class file by fully-qualified name, look for the method there, and throw an exception if it's not there. You need to find a different way to split your code into multiple classes.

Comment: So how does Java resolve cases where you have a library that has a class with the same package name as one of your modules?

Comment: It uses the class from the jar that comes earlier in the classpath.

Comment: You can read this if you want to know in details how class loading works in java - http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Classloaders-Demystified-Understanding-How-Java-Classes-Get-Loaded-in-Web-Applications

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are in different package, it is possible by adding Qualifier.

@Qualifier("yourClassQualifierName1")

@Qualifier("yourClassQualifierName2")